# Value type of BFTask has no member Generator: Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: userName)
    var objects = query.findObjectsInBackground()

    self.resultsImageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    **for object in objects {**  
        self.resultsImageFiles.append(object["photo"] as! PFFile)
        self.resultsImageFiles[0].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        }
    }
}
```

So I've spent this morning looking around the site/googling and maybe I am just dense but I can't seem to find the answer to my error. The error is, as I stated in the title: **value type of BFTask has no member generator**.

It is located in the line **for object in objects**. I have tried to unwrap it, but it did not work (maybe because the option is not meant to be nil)? Any ideas? Thanks, 
Brock

Comment: Take a look at the documentation. All of it has been updated for Swift 2. https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot :) I figured it out! Added in a findobjectsthebackgroundwithblock with the PFObject and it fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findObjectInBackground()` [returns an object representing a background task](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/findObjectsInBackground), not an array. At the place in your code you’ve put the for loop, the background task may not have even completed yet.

You need to wait for it to complete and then extract its results by using [`continueWithBlock`](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS#the-continuewithblock-method), which will give you the array you’re looking for.

Comment: cheers mate! Totally didn't think of reading that documentation :D